# RadialGauge UWP Binding

Tags: c#, binding, uwp

i am trying to bind a value to a radial Gauge:

```
  <Controls:RadialGauge 
              x:Name="Warm"
              Grid.Column="1"
              Value="{x:Bind Zahl.Pulse.ausgabeMilli , Mode=TwoWay}" //BINDING
              Minimum="0"
              Maximum="100"
              StepSize="1"
              IsInteractive="True"
              TickSpacing="10"
              ScaleWidth="20"
              MinAngle="210"
              MaxAngle="150"
              Unit="Temperatur"
              TickBrush="Red"
              TrailBrush="Red"
              ScaleTickBrush="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}"
              ScaleBrush="Gray"
              UnitBrush ="Black"
              ValueBrush ="Black"
              NeedleWidth="0" 
              TickLength="0" />
    </Grid>
```

but getting this error.

"Invalid binding path 'Zahl.Pulse.ausgabeMilli' : Cannot bind type 'System.Single' to 'System.Double' without a converter"

Answer (score 0):

x:Bind is pretty picky about type conversions, far more so than normal binding. In this case, you're giving it a `float`/`single` value, but it's expecting a `double` and it has no conversion code between the two (for some reason?)

You can either use a converter or function binding to convert your float to a double, or use normal Binding which should do the conversion automatically.

Comment: Normal Binding with like Value="{Binding Zahl.Pulse.ausgabeMilli}" also not working.

Comment: For normal binding you may need to change your Binding path as your DataContext usually isn't automatically the same as x:Bind's default context (which is the owning control). DataContext is usually null by default